# regular expression for perl : windows programming

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module, mod-perl

I want a perl regular expression **which will print the files name those have only .txt** extension at the end nothing else.

I have written a reg exp but it is printing all the files with extension .txt also .txt* files. That I dont want

```
if($filename=~m/xxx\\.txt/i)
```

I have now also tried the following, but it is also not working

```
if($filename=~m/xxx\\.txt$/i)
```

Answer (score 2):

you need the $ boundary to indicate end of string.

```
if ($filename =~ m/\.txt$/i)
```

Note, you can also use a [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to get all the text files

```
my @textfiles = <*.txt>;
```

Comment: Use exactly what I've given you.  In your example you have an escaped backslach, along with the literal string `xxx`.  You just need `\.txt$` include the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be that Windows is adding funny things at end of file names?
Try:

```
if($filename =~ /\.txt\s*/)
```